# JavaScript Callback after calling function

Tags: javascript, callback

Ok so lets say I have this function:

```
function a(message) {
alert(message);
}
```

And I want to have a callback after the alert window is shown. Something like this:

```
a("Hi.", function() {});
```

I'm not sure how to have a callback inside of the function I call like that.

(I'm just using the alert window as an example)

Thanks!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There's no special syntax for callbacks, just pass the callback function and call it inside your function.

```
function a(message, cb) {
    console.log(message); // log to the console of recent Browsers
    cb();
}

a("Hi.", function() {
    console.log("After hi...");
});
```

Output:

```
Hi.
After hi...
```

Answer (score 6):

You can add a if statement to check whether you add a callback function or not. So you can use the function also without a callback.

```
function a(message, cb) {
    alert(message);
    if (typeof cb === "function") {
        cb();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that will alert first and then second. I hope this is what you asked.

```
function  basic(callback) {
    alert("first...");
    var a = "second...";
    callback(a);
} 

basic(function (abc) {
   alert(abc);
});
```